# Tags hierarchy search on elasticsearch

Tags: search, elasticsearch

I have a database of tagged photos, and separately I have the hierarchy of tags. I want to enrich my search using elasticsearch, so that.

**Photo**

> tags: ["Mercedes-Benz", "motor sport", "red"]

should match when I search for `car` or `color`.

If I use synonyms based analyzer: 

`Mercedes-Benz=>Mercede-Benz,car,transportation`

`Mercedes-Benz` is being transformed into `Mercedes-Benz`, `car` and `transportation` during indexing, this part is correct.

When I search for `Mercedes-Benz` it brings all `car` and `transportation` results too, because field is analyzed in the same way as during indexing.

What analyzer I should use for this kind of hierarchical search, maybe path_hierarchy?

Comment: You should use that analyzer only during indexing and not at search time. In your mapping you should specify `"search_analyzer": "standard"` for the `tags` field, so that "Mercedes-Benz" won't go through the same synonym matching process.

Comment: Thanks a lot, didn't know about that possibility.